# Design Mode in Excel/VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

On the Excel Ribbon and the VBA-editor I can activate the so called "Design Mode". As far as I understand the only thing "design mode" does is to "deactivate" all userform elements on the worksheets so a left click only selects them instead of triggering their events.

Is there anything else "Design Mode" does when it's turned on in regards to when it's turned off (particular within the VBA-editor)?

EDIT: Note, quite a few article say I can not run code wihle in design mode, which is only partly true. As far as I see e.g. macros can not be executed by command buttons etc. that are placed on the worksheet (as I explained in my question), but code can be started via keyboard shortcuts, VBA-editor etc. without explicitly ending design mode.

Answer (score 1):

Design Mode contradicts run/debug mode.

In Design Mode you cannot use the debugging tools, except for setting breakpoints
and creating watch expressions.

When you Run the VBA code, you in effect exit from Design Mode.

See
[Visual Basic Concepts - Design Time, Run Time, and Break Mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa716232%28v=vs.60%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: As far as I understand your answer is "yes": in addition to the changes within the front end (which I described in the question) certain debug tools won't work any more. Which are those exactly?

Comment: Certainly not a Yes. Debug itself will not work in this mode, only setting up for debug is possible. Setting breakpoints and creating watch expressions is something you can do in any mode.

Comment: I don't really see any actual difference here, but maybe I misunderstand. I can't find any feature that doesn't work within the design mode. How exactly can I verify that debug modus doesn't work in design mode but works otherwise?

Comment: Run the VBA macro and then see that you are out of Design Mode.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I'm leaving design mode when I start a macro. I don't understand what you mean by "cannot use the debugging tools". Can you name a specific tool I can not use while in design mode?

Comment: I meant that as you cannot debug, then also you cannot use the debugging tools, only set breakpoints and watch expressions, which isn't much.

Comment: That is the same I can do after exiting design mode (without going into run/break mode). So I would argue in regards to debug tools (breakpoints etc.) there is actually no difference when turning on design mode (in regards to turning it off).

Comment: If you wish so.

Comment: Well, I don't know, that's why I was asking in the first place. ; ) You said in your answer that certain debugging tools won't work when turning on design mode. I can't find any specific tools for which this is the case. Just trying to understand your answer.

Comment: Any attempt to debug needs running and that will get you out of Design Mode, so the question, to my mind, doesn't really arise.